# How to force kill program stuck while accessing IO (firefox)

Tags: firefox, kill, io

I use firefox to display some files over an sshfs mountpoint...

However, it happens that this mountpoint gets disconnected; if I inadvertantly reload a page, firefox will be forever stuck and **cannot even be killed**.

For example, I still see a firefox process with "`D`" here:

```
$ ps aux | grep firefox
plasmab    10269  0.8  4.2 3253252 344216 ?      D    18:12   0:51 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
plasmab    13350  0.0  0.0  21996  1148 pts/3    S+   19:50   0:00 grep --color=auto firefox
```

and this, even after `killall -9 firefox`.
Trying `kill -9 10269` is useless.

Now, I followed [steps to remove the `lock` and `.parentlock` files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78689/152329), but after that I still see the "D" process. Nonetheless I restarted Firefox and closed it again, which caused the unwanted process to disappear...

So removing the lock files *and* relaunching firefox despite the stuck process worked. Is there a better way though?

I suspect this question could be more general. For example I could be stuck doing a simple `ls`. How to kill such stuck processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process in `D` state is in uninterruptable sleep. No signal will kill it until its wait is over. Often the cause is incomplete I/O.

In your case, the connection, though lost, has not been closed. Either there is still some retrying to do or it it is at CLOSE_WAIT state. If you wait long enough, `kill` will work, but only after `sshfs` gives up.

You should kill the `sshfs` process first, and only then firefox, that will no longer have something to wait for, because the underlying filesystem will be gone (no more `sshfs`).

So, the quick fix:

- kill sshfs
- kill firefox

You might also want to look into the `-o reconnect` option of `sshfs`.